# How to save printed console output to pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a printed output:

```
{-1: [2, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19, 24, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 40, 42, 49, 54, 56, 59, 64, 66, 78, 94, 99, 101, 102, 103, 106, 107, 109, 110, 114, 117, 123, 126, 127, 129, 131, 132, 133, 136, 144, 146, 147, 150, 155, 156, 164, 166, 177, 179, 181, 182, 188, 190, 192, 194, 201, 202, 204, 209, 214, 217, 220, 221, 225, 231, 232, 234, 235, 236, 240, 244, 246, 248, 253, 254, 257, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 268, 271, 275, 277, 279, 280, 281, 285, 286, 287, 288, 297, 302, 309, ...], 0: [3, 6, 8, 25, 27, 33, 38, 57, 62, 63, 67, 69, 70, 72, 74, 83, 89, 91, 92, 98, 111, 112, 122, 124, 135, 158, 175, 187, 197, 198, 199, 200, 205, 206, 207, 215, 216, 242, 243, 258, 267, 272, 283, 299, 300, 303, 305, 306, 307, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 319, 326, 329, 348, 353, 355, 376, 377, 378, 380, 385, 386, 387, 389, 399, 402, 406, 418, 424, 425, 426, 427, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 447, 486, 487, 503, 511, 512, 514, 515, 524, 525, 535, 536, 539, 547, 549, 550, 554, ...], 1: [0, 5, 21, 44, 46, 48, 51, 82, 115, 118, 274, 293, 330, 331, 332, 361, 401, 413, 507, 520, 522, 523, 558, 560, 643, 650, 681, 700, 734, 747, 753, 782, 784, 836, 839, 893, 905, 934, 951, 976, 999, 1037, 1048, 1052, 1053, 1082, 1109, 1113, 1115, 1121, 1139, 1146, 1219, 1221, 1264, 1355, 1382, 1392, 1432, 1467, 1485, 1490, 1497, 1513, 1526, 1565, 1682, 1728, 1737, 1738, 1806, 1815, 1824, 1828, 1844, 1845, 1885, 1959, 2014, 2017, 2029, 2052, 2072, 2153, 2157, 2168, 2193, 2199, 2214, 2228, 2232, 2240, 2243, 2264, 2300, 2317, 2353, 2376, 2402, 2405, ...], 2: [15, 39, 60, 61, 149, 157, 222, 250, 289, 320, 448, 538, 630, 658, 662, 665, 709, 759, 810, 837, 897, 901, 917, 924, 925, 945, 946, 954, 959, 1049, 1050, 1090, 1131, 1140, 1154, 1172, 1251, 1300, 1313, 1328, 1387, 1393, 1431, 1440, 1448, 1475, 1507, 1535, 1591, 1597, 1603, 1615, 1636, 1705, 1725, 1736, 1771, 1777, 1791, 1796, 1855, 1867, 1903, 1918, 1928, 1930, 1942, 1943, 1989, 2021, 2039, 2095, 2119, 2169, 2195, 2309, 2337, 2418, 2426, 2429, 2522, 2582, 2598, 2678, 2679, 2682], 3: [50, 113, 160, 213, 224, 229, 238, 239, 352, 400, 409, 506, 545, 570, 701, 703, 712, 716, 830, 838, 858, 921, 1008, 1078, 1124, 1130, 1194, 1214, 1305, 1308, 1311, 1360, 1421, 1441, 1473, 1476, 1532, 1533, 1548, 1580, 1616, 1622, 1649, 1679, 1735, 1883, 1897, 1920, 1985, 2015, 2084, 2091, 2097, 2118, 2152, 2181, 2212, 2223, 2237, 2249, 2310, 2313, 2347, 2369, 2381, 2390, 2470, 2496, 2511, 2514, 2529, 2549, 2569, 2601, 2626, 2666, 2688],
```

Is it possible i can put this to dataframe
, suppose to column: For example:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | [2, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19, 24, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 40, 42, 49, 54, 56, 59, 64, 66, 78, 94, 99, 101, 102, 103, 106, 107, 109, 110, 114, 117, 123, 126, 127, 129, 131, 132, 133, 136, 144, 146, 147, 150, 155, 156, 164, 166, 177, 179, 181, 182, 188, 190, 192, 194, 201, 202, 204, 209, 214, 217, 220, 221, 225, 231, 232, 234, 235, 236, 240, 244, 246, 248, 253, 254, 257, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 268, 271, 275, 277, 279, 280, 281, 285, 286, 287, 288, 297, 302, 309, ...] |
| 0 | [3, 6, 8, 25, 27, 33, 38, 57, 62, 63, 67, 69, 70, 72, 74, 83, 89, 91, 92, 98, 111, 112, 122, 124, 135, 158, 175, 187, 197, 198, 199, 200, 205, 206, 207, 215, 216, 242, 243, 258, 267, 272, 283, 299, 300, 303, 305, 306, 307, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 319, 326, 329, 348, 353, 355, 376, 377, 378, 380, 385, 386, 387, 389, 399, 402, 406, 418, 424, 425, 426, 427, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 447, 486, 487, 503, 511, 512, 514, 515, 524, 525, 535, 536, 539, 547, 549, 550, 554, ...], |

Comment: I think pandas have a function for that

Comment: Could you please tell me the function? i tried many things but since the arrays are of different length, i am unable to save it to a dataframe, Thank you in advance. @Copperfield

Comment: `pd.Series(the_dict).reset_index(name='Value')`.

Comment: the answers look better than what I have in mind, what I was thinking was one of the read variant `pandas.read_*` like read_clipboard or read_json

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Value"] = list(d.values())
df.index = d.keys()

# OR

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: [v] for k, v in d.items()},
                            orient="index",
                            columns=["Value"])

print(df)
#                                                 Value
# -1  [2, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19, 24, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35...
#  0  [3, 6, 8, 25, 27, 33, 38, 57, 62, 63, 67, 69, ...
#  1  [0, 5, 21, 44, 46, 48, 51, 82, 115, 118, 274, ...
#  2  [15, 39, 60, 61, 149, 157, 222, 250, 289, 320,...
#  3  [50, 113, 160, 213, 224, 229, 238, 239, 352, 4...
```

Comment: Hi, it works fully, but is there a way i can print the whole without  truncation? and also my output is binded by Int64Index([ x,y,z.....]), can you please let me know how to remove that?@d.b

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    -1: [2, 10, 11],
    0: [3, 6, 27, 33],
    1: [0, 5, 21],
    2: [15],
    3: [50, 113, 160, 213, 224],
}


df = pd.DataFrame({"Number": dct.keys(), "Value": dct.values()})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Number                     Value
0      -1               [2, 10, 11]
1       0            [3, 6, 27, 33]
2       1                [0, 5, 21]
3       2                      [15]
4       3  [50, 113, 160, 213, 224]
```

Comment: Hi, this code works fully, its just that i get truncation in between, is there a way i can get the whole without truncation?